# jqtransform - set textbox width

Tags: jquery, jqtransform

I am using the jqtransform jquery plugin to change the look and feel of my form elements. However, I am unable to override the width of a text input element - no matter how I style the element it is overriden. Is there any known way to override this property?

Thanks in advance,

JP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the reasons are:

1. Each form element has it's own wrapping `div`
2. The `width` is hardcoded (by js) in `style` attribute, so overriding this in CSS doesn't work
3. jqtransform does not provide element ids, so you have to set it manually somehow or operate with classes

So, in your case I'd suggest you to use some jquery:

```
var myW = 300;
$("#elementId").css("width", myW);
$("#elementId").parents(".jqTransformInputWrapper").css("width", myW);
```

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to revive an old question but the current answer makes it more complicated than necessary.

The easiest way is to simply set the 'size' HTML attribute on your input element:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.SomeProperty, new{ size="4" })
```

Then at runtime jqTransform calculates the div width (extracted from jqTransform source file):

```
var inputSize=$input.width();
if($input.attr('size')){
       inputSize = $input.attr('size')*10;
       $input.css('width',inputSize);
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the latest version or only works when making the div wider than the content. I have a dropdown that has very long content and setting the size to a smaller width doesn't affect how it is rendered even when firebug shows the select has the attribute value for size.

Comment: JQTransform only utilizes the above code chunk for textboxes.

To have it work for select lists (and/or other input types), you will need to replicate the code block into the other sections of JQTransform's source code :(

Answer (score 0):

I got an easy solution, you must "configure" the size attribute of the text input just before the jqtransform usage declaration, The quote from protektor is right, is 20 of size attribute given by jquery, it's detecting the default size of a text input and multiplied by 10. So basicly you can give a standard size if you want on this way:

```
$("form input:text").attr("size", x);
$("form").jqTransform();
```

where "x" is the size, its a number, is not pixel measure, remember jquery calculates pixels multiplying this number by ten. If you want 400px on the input text, then you must set size at 40 and you done.